# Why the different performance with Android, Canvas and DrawBitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have to draw a bitmap from int arrays and am looking for the fastest way possible to achieve this. I did some performance testing with canvas and drawbitmap.

I benched a loop of doing calls to:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(a1, 0, b1.getWidth(), x, y, cx, cy, true, null);
```

against the same loop doing:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(b1, new Rect(0,0,cx,cy), new Rect(x,y,cx+x,cy+y), null);
```

with following values:

```
b1    -> transparent 8888 bitmap
a1    -> int array with the color values of the b1
x,y   -> position 
cx/cy -> size
```

And the description for the drawbitmap call with the int values says:

***"Treat the specified array of colors as a bitmap, and draw it. This gives the same result as first creating a bitmap from the array, and then drawing it, but this method avoids explicitly creating a bitmap object which can be more efficient if the colors are changing often."***

My problem now is that drawing the bitmap with int array or the bitmap directly looks exactly the same but using the bitmap is more than twice as fast than the int array (43 fps instead of 20). It does state that it doesn't create a bitmap and as such I hope it avoids unnecessary and time consuming copying of the data and draws it directly to the canvas.

Is there a bug or oversight in my code (I only exchange the one line and it does look the same) or am I doing something completely wrong ?

Comment: One possible way to investigate this would be to compare corresponding Android source code.

Comment: Well, I do not think that is a feasible option because I would take me ages to find out whats going on in there...